# Need suggestions for ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I would like to use more client-side scripts on my aspx page. I'm not an expert in this area and I'm a bit overwhelmed at the options. First, let me spell out what the page is displaying and then what I am trying to accomplish.

**The Page:**
The page containts a GridView (on the left-hand side) which is pulling data from a DB for different types of products a user can request. For example's sake, let's say we have table, chair, and couch.

**What I want to Accomplish:**
When the user clicks on a row of the GridView (let's say "table"), the ID of that selected row and the title is copied over to the right-hand side of the page into an accordion pane (or a similar display). The header of the accordion pane will be "Product: Table". When the accordion is expanded, the user has the option to specify the color and size of the table (via check boxes, text boxes, etc.). So essentially this is shopping cart functionality on the right-hand side of this page.

I should also point out I would like a "remove" button for each pane in the accordion so it can dynamically be deleted.

What is the best option for this situation? Should I use jQuery, AJAX (AJAX Control Toolkit?), a combination or a different tool? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Personally, I would use some 3rd party library. We use [DevExpress's tools](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Demos.xml) for most of our business applications (although they do not use jQuery).

Comment: Is it an AJAX Control Toolkit accordion? Or is that what you're asking about as well?

Comment: @ ianpgall, It can be any accordion, AJAX Control Toolkit or jQuery. I'm open to suggestions/recommendations.

Comment: @ Uwe, thank for your suggestion. If possible, I'd like to stick to free options for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [knockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/) because it's easy to use, has reasonable documentation and good online support. At a glance it looks easy than backbone as well (I don't know backbone).

I would not use the AJAX Control Toolkit unless I had too. I HATE the ajax toolkit as everything happens 'by magic' and once you step off the path shown in the simple demo's you are dead.

Knockout does require a little investment of time, but I consider it a great framework for web apps that require moderate javaScript use.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Looks like a good solution for what I'm trying to acheieve. However I am new to this technology and I can't seem to find any tutorials for using knockoutjs with a GridView control. I mostly see code written to work with plain html. Would you know of a good tutorial/resource for binding to a server control?

Comment: Good question. I would find it easier to use a client side grid, like the knockout grid [  http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html ] as trying to connect a server control like the gridview to knockout could be quite painful. The difficulties you are facing with GV and the AJAX Toolkit highlight why a lot of devs, given the choice, have moved away from those technologies; What in the MS demo's looks great, becomes like running uphill - through treacle - in reality.

Comment: That's unfortunate to hear. Can the knockout grid bind to a SQL Server DB as easily as GridView?

Comment: Also, This is perhaps a very novice question but is it recommended to use knockout (MVVC design) with ASP.NET Web Forms website? Or was knockout created with the intention to work better alogside an ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: Knockout was made in the 'era' of asp.net mvc but it can be used with a webforms page - any jquery/knockout ajax calls would connect with a webservice, not the code behind. If you are currently using webforms and have no experience with knockout perhaps it might be best to stick with GridViews and the AJAX toolkit - I haven't used either for years so I'm not sure I can help much further, sorry about that.